# No query results for model App/Models/Country delete_all

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working on project useing laravel and vuejs the problem is that I am trying to select multi rows and delete them the error is 
No query results for model [App\Models\Country] delete_all
 my route link

```
Route::delete('/delete_all','CountriesController@deleteAll');
```

delete function in the country controller

```
public function deleteAll(Request $request){
    $ids = $request->ids;
    DB::table("countries")->whereIn('id',explode(",",$ids))->delete();
    return response()->json('Selected Countries Deleted Successfully',200);
}
```

the delete method in the component

```
delAll(){
         axios.delete('/dashboard/countries/delete_all', {
              ids: this.selected
          }).then(response => {
                 toastr.success(response.data);
         })
      }
```

where can I find the Error

Comment: Try with   DB::table("countries")->whereIn('id',explode(",",$ids))->get()->delete();   Seems you've missed the    ->get()

Comment: In the controller, what's the structure of the value of the `$ids` variable? Please add a `print_r` of this variable.

Comment: @boolfalse No, you don't call `->get()` before `->delete()`. The `Builder` class has a `delete` function.

Comment: @Tim Lewis you're right

Comment: you shouldn't be getting an error such as "No query results for **model**" if you are using Query Builder directly like your code above is. That error is from the `ModelNotFoundException`, which is from using the Eloquent Builder/Relationships or Route Model Bindings for the most part

Comment: I tried to add get() to my code but still the same

Answer (score 0):

just trying

```
DB::table("countries")->whereIn('id',explode(",",$ids))->get()->delete();
```

or simple

```
Countries::destroy(explode(",",$ids));
```

Comment: i want to see the model the controller and dd($ids) or print_r($ids) to see what is the ids structure because it should work